# Pass an element ID from component to component (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning!

I am building an Angular application and I want to perform a simple toggle of a sidenav. The composition of the html goes like this:

`app.component.html`

```html
<div class = "main-container">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  ...
  <mat-sidenav-container class = "example-sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav>
       ...
    </mat-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

`navbar.component.html` (that has the app-navbar selector)

```html
<mat-toolbar color = "primary" class = "topbar telative">
  <button mat-icon-button (click) = "snav.toggle()">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Whenever I try to click the button that should open/close the sidenav, an error `Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined` raises. I guess it is because the element `#snav` is not defined in the same component as the click event that should trigger it. Could someone please indicate me how to pass this reference from one element to another? Also, if possible, could someone please give me an explanation of what the `#` syntax does in an Angular element.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

In navbar.component.ts you can use @output to emit event for open/close menu.

```
@Output() toggleSidenav = new EventEmitter();
```

and in navbar.component.html emit the event.

```
<mat-toolbar color = "primary" class = "topbar telative">
  <button mat-icon-button (click) = "toggleSidenav.emit()">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
   </button>
</mat-toolbar`
```

and in last in app.component.html get the event of toggle menu

```
<app-navbar (toggleSidenav)="snav.toggle()"></app-navbar>
```

Just Try it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Would you mind to explain a little bit more, if possible?

Comment: Our side navbar container is in parent component and our menu button is in child component   so I have used @output which is used to emit event from parent to child. So when click on menu button I have emit that event using `toggleSidenav.emit()`  and in parent component  I have getting that event using '(toggleSidenav)' and in this event  I am toggle the nav.

Comment: You can also take a look @output here; https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Stackblitz working with your code (I made minor changes).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-angularmaterial?file=src/app/navbar/navbar.component.html
The # is part of the @ViewChild('somename') syntax and it is used in the html template to specify that you are listening to your child component who is sending information in the 'somename' variable (you then use in the template '#somename').

Look at these examples:
https://www.centric.eu/NL/Default/Craft/Blogs/2018/01/25/Angular-components-How-to-talk-to-your-children-and-listen-to-what-they-have-to-say

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858)  It's great to have examples, but the code should be part of your answer (primary) and any offsite resources should be secondary.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ErikPhilips, I'm learning how to use Stackoverflow and hopefully help some colleagues. Will improve on this :)